# How do I keep VBA from putting output into the active sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a bunch of csv files that have been pulled into a single workbook.  I'm trying them all together into a single report.  at the end, i'm putting the data into a single array and then into a single sheet.

Whenever I run the sub, however, it load the data into the active sheet.  How do I get the data to show up in the same sheet, regardless of where I am in the workbook?

here's what I have:

```
Dim starting_cell_range As Range
Set starting_cell_range = Range(find_last_column("Data_History")) 

Dim n As Integer
With Worksheets("Data_History")
    For n = 0 To 18
        starting_cell_range.Offset(n, 1) = final_array(n)
    Next n

End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the range before you get the sheet:

```
Set starting_cell_range = Range(find_last_column("Data_History")) 'this is using the active sheet

Dim n As Integer
With Worksheets("Data_History") 'this is the sheet you want
```

So just move the line that sets the range to after you have the sheet defined.  And remember to use `.Range` instead of `Range` since you are in a `with` block (it is like calling `Worksheets("Data_History").Range(...)`

Here is the full code:

```
Dim starting_cell_range As Range

Dim n As Integer
With Worksheets("Data_History")
    Set starting_cell_range = .Range(find_last_column("Data_History"))
    For n = 0 To 18
        starting_cell_range.Offset(n, 1) = final_array(n)
    Next n

End With
```

Comment: nailed it.  Thanks!  much better understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you defined the range, it is automatically defined in the activesheet.  Putting it in a With block, doesn't change the definition of the range.  Try this:

```
Dim CurrWB As Workbook
Dim WSToCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim starting_cell_range As Range
Set CurrWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set WSToCopyTo = CurrWB.Sheets("Data_History") 
Set starting_cell_range = WSToCopyTo.Range(find_last_column("Data_History")) 

Dim n As Integer
For n = 0 To 18
    starting_cell_range.Offset(n, 1) = final_array(n)
Next n
```

The With block wasn't doing anything, so I took it out.